# Compiling PDAL with both Python2 and Python3 bindings support

Tags: python, pdal, compilation

I would like to build [PDAL](https://pdal.io/) with both together support for Python2 *and* Python3 bindings (on Ubuntu 16.04).

[image: PDAL support is an OR statement]

Fig. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fev7k.png): *Screenshot of the Python stuff within cmake-gui.*

How could I achieve this?
If a re-compile with Python3 support I end up with such error message when installing, so I have to uninstall it before, which will uninstall the Python2 bindings... :

```
Selecting previously unselected package pdal-1.7.1-py3.
(Reading database ... 546498 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pdal-1.7.1-py3_20180920-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pdal-1.7.1-py3 (20180920-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /opt/PDAL/build/pdal-1.7.1-py3_20180920-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/local/bin/pdal', which is also in package pdal-1.7.1 20180823-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /opt/PDAL/build/pdal-1.7.1-py3_20180920-1_amd64.deb
/var/tmp/tmp.TeaEeCUL0y/dpkginstall.log (END)
```

Comment: I doubt your goal is achievable. Namespace collisions make it unlikely that this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible because of the way PDAL embeds Python. A future release may change this situation, but PDAL at the moment compiles against the Python and Numpy headers and they cannot mix versions.

Comment: Note this was fixed as of PDAL 2.1. The Python support for PDAL is now available via PyPI and requires scikit-build to install.